# 2 values in checkbox type

Tags: php, laravel

I want make function who can switch 2 values - Yes and No in Database. Now i have checkbox type who get me 1 value - "Yes" and when is not checked dont give me value. I want make in controller to switch when I dont get value to switch to "No" value. Now my function work, but change only last result, not this who i want. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnO4W.png & https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydrgF.png. This is my code

```
<form method="post" action="/adminpanel/hofswitch">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="card-body">
                                @foreach($char as $value)

                                <div class="card-body">
                                @if($value->status == "Yes")
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="switch[]" value="{{$value->id}}" checked data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success">

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-form-label" for="inputSuccess"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Character Class</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="class[]" value="{{$value->class}}" class="form-control is-valid" id="inputSuccess" readonly="true" placeholder="{{$value->class}}">
                                    </div>
                                    @else
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="switch[]" value="{{$value->id}}" data-bootstrap-switch data-off-color="danger" data-on-color="success">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-form-label" for="inputError"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i> Character Class</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="class[]" value="{{$value->class}}" class="form-control is-invalid" id="inputError" readonly="true" placeholder="{{$value->class}}">
                                        </div>
                                    @endif
                                </div>

                            @endforeach

                                <!-- /.card-body -->

                                    <div class="card-footer">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-12">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                        </form>
```

and Controller

```
 public function hof_switch(Request $request) {
    $count = count(collect($request->get('switch')));

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $switch = $request->switch[$i] ?? null;

    if ($switch == true) {
        $switch = "Yes";
    } else {
        $switch = "No";
    }

    $update = DB::connection('XWEB')->table('XWEB_HOF')
        ->where('id', $request->switch[$i])
        ->update(
            [
                'status' => $switch,
            ]);
}

return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('You have switch this class successfully!');
```

}

Comment: You should be using a radio button to handle this. You also need to do $request->get('switch'); because right now you are using the same name for multiple elements and just doesn't make sense. Therefore you would not need the for loop.

Comment: @AlexMac can this work with checkbox or no have chance?

Comment: There's two common ways to solve this. Either make your `name` attribute unique (but still an array) for each interation of the loop, such as `name="switch-{{$value->id}}[]"`, or use a shared name like you are but make the value itself unqiue, such as `name="switch[]" value="{{value->id}}"`. The fact that a checkbox is sent in the first place implies "Yes", so sending that literally doesn't do anything.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I update first post with new code, but still dont work. Now when i try to pick "No" dont work. With "Yes" work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fews days ago I've been in similar problem
Put a hidden input with same name, and then try to POST it.
If the checkbox is checked, than the value will be send 1.
And If the checkbox isn't checked, than the value will be send only 0.

```
<form>
 <input type="hidden" name="switch[]" value="0">
 <input type="checkbox" name="switch[]" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: When is "checked" give me both values - 0 and 1

Comment: Did you put the `hidden` input field at the top?